# How to remove a column of words in a document term matrix?

Tags: text-mining, tm

I trained my machine learning model using training dataset via a document term matrix.
I am trying to predict my test dataset but unfortunately it contains words that the training dataset does not come with.

My question is how do I actually remove those words in my test dataset that is not found in the training dataset.

I am using tm package and I created a DocumentTermMatrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is with the **quanteda** text analysis package.  Once you construct a document-feature matrix, you can select its features from a second "dfm".  This allows you to construct a dfm for a training set, and then easily select those features from a test set that are common with those in the training set.

Here is an illustration, from the `?selectFeatures` help page:

```
require(quanteda)
textVec1 <- c("This is text one.", "This, the second text.", "Here: the third text.")
textVec2 <- c("Here are new words.", "New words in this text.")
features(dfm1 <- dfm(textVec1))
#
#   ... lowercasing
#   ... tokenizing
#   ... indexing documents: 3 documents
#   ... indexing features: 8 feature types
#   ... created a 3 x 8 sparse dfm
#   ... complete. 
# Elapsed time: 0.077 seconds.
# [1] "this"   "is"     "text"   "one"    "the"    "second" "here"   "third" 

features(dfm2a <- dfm(textVec2))
#
#   ... lowercasing
#   ... tokenizing
#   ... indexing documents: 2 documents
#   ... indexing features: 7 feature types
#   ... created a 2 x 7 sparse dfm
#   ... complete. 
# Elapsed time: 0.006 seconds.
# [1] "here"  "are"   "new"   "words" "in"    "this"  "text" 

(dfm2b <- selectFeatures(dfm2a, dfm1))
# found 3 features from 8 supplied types in a dfm, padding 0s for another 5 
# Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 8 features.
# 2 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#       this is text one the second here third
# text1    0  0    0   0   0      0    1     0
# text2    1  0    1   0   0      0    0     0
identical(features(dfm1), features(dfm2b))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this. One is that when you created your DTM using the training data you have a list of items, then you can write a small function that does the work for you of joining those lists, here an example, maybe not efficient but should work:

dtm is the corpus you built with the training data. Document is your new document you want to evaluate your model with:

```
    DocumentVectortfidf<-function (dtm, Document) #
        {

          corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(Document))

          dtm1 <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus) #this is from your Document

    #I created 2 dataframes and then merge them.

          Data<-data.frame(dtm1$dimnames$Terms,dtm1$v)
          colnames(Data)[1:2]<-c("Words","Frequency")

          Matrixwords<-data.frame(dtm$dimnames$Terms,0)
          colnames(Matrixwords)[1]<-"Words"

          Joint<-merge(Matrixwords,Data, by="Words", all.x = T, sort=T)
          Joint$Frequency<-ifelse(is.na(Joint$Frequency),0,Joint$Frequency)

         # This is optional if you want tf or tfidf, just change this, important!!
 tf uses only values from the Document, but tfidf uses numbers along the entire
 list of documents, so you use dtm for this. 
         # cs <- col_sums(dtm > 0)
         # lnrs <- log2(nDocs(dtm)/cs)

      DocumentVector<-data.frame(t(Joint$Frequency*lnrs))

      DocumentVector 
    }
```

Now there are several different ways of doing this, can be done as a dictionary too, so we extract the list of words from dtm(the one with training data) and then use this list as a dictionary when creating the dtm1 for the new Document. 
 I hope this helps.